# Understanding how work with flexible in-app updates

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-snackbar, in-app-update

I'm trying to implement in-app updates in my application but I'm facing a doubt about how to work with flexible updates. I will show the flexible update to the user in the splash screen when the user open the application, what I need to do before this? Can the user navigate on the application or I need to force the user to keeps on the splash screen until the update are done?

My doubt about this it's because of the snackbar that I want to show to her when the update are done, notifying the user to restart the app, but if I initiate the in-app update listener in the splash and let the user continue the navigation, how can I show the snackbar?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to implement in-app updates in my application but I'm facing a doubt about how to work with flexible updates. I will show the flexible update to the user in the splash screen when the user open the application, what I need to do before this?

Your question is unclear. Your user opens the app, you present the option to update in the background. OK. So ... what else needs to happen "before this"?

> Can the user navigate on the application or I need to force the user to keeps on the splash screen until the update are done?

Allowing the user to navigate the application is [exactly the purpose of doing a flexible update](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#flexible).

> My doubt about this it's because of the snackbar that I want to show to her when the update are done, notifying the user to restart the app, but if I initiate the in-app update listener in the splash and let the user continue the navigation, how can I show the snackbar?

Have you read [the documentation that explains exactly how to do this](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#flexible)?